# Erro ao compilar projeto com VB 6. Passar para .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-basic-6

Não sou desenvolvedor em VB. Peguei um projeto para 5 dias, por meio de uma consultoria, mas deveria ser tudo em `SQL Server`. Bem, acontece, que alguma alteração em tela deve ser feito. Abri o VB 6(Compilador) e selecionei o projet.vbp e ao carregar, gerou vários erros. Fui dar o F5 para rodar e está dando a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi gerado vários logs de erros, os quais seleciono esses:

frmCadBeneficios.log

> Line 242: Class MSMask.MaskEdBox of control mskDtInicioPlano was not a
>   loaded control class. Line 267: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control
>   dtpDataContrato was not a loaded control class. Line 288: Class
>   MSMask.MaskEdBox of control mskDataOpcaoContrato was not a loaded
>   control class.

frmRelRelatorioMedico.log

> Line 131: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtpInicio was not a
>   loaded control class. Line 152: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control
>   dtpFinal was not a loaded control class.

frmRelPortaria.log

> Line 151: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtpDataPeriodo was not a
>   loaded control class. Line 172: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control
>   dtpDataPeriodo_Fim was not a loaded control class. Line 193: Class
>   MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtpDataAdmissao was not a loaded control
>   class.

Acho que esses são suficientes, mas são mais de 20 formulários. Não sei o que é, e nem sei o que fazer.

No aguardo dos colegas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixe os controles:

- `MSMask.MaskEdBox` -> MSMASK32.OCX
- `MSComCtl2.DTPicker` -> MSCOMCT2.OCX

Após baixar, registre estes controles:

1. Abra o prompt de comando como administrador;
2. Navegue até a pasta que baixou os .OCX;
3. Execute o regsvr32: `c:\downloads> regsvr32 MSMASK32.OCX`
4. `c:\downloads> regsvr32 MSCOMCT2.OCX`

Agora, em seu projeto no VB6, adicione-os nas referências do seu projeto. Como fazemos no .NET.

[Como adicionar ou remover referências usando a caixa de diálogo Adicionar Referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pode haver a necessidade de ter que baixar o Visual Studio com ServicePack6 para atender a sua demanda para VB6. Se o seu VB estiver instalado em Windows 7, 8 ou 10, você pode ter alguma dificuldade, mas há muitos tutoriais Windows que lhe ajudaram.
E porque ter que instalar o SP6?
Se sua aplicação foi desenvolvida em SP6, pode ser que ocorra alguma incompatibilidade dos controles MSMASK32.OCX e MSMASK32.OCX dentro do projeto.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O VB está instalado em uma VM com Windows XP

Comment: Tentou instalar o Service Pack 6 na VM?